# Python script shebang behavior

Tags: python, shebang

I have a python script, in which I have the following shebang `#!/usr/bin/python`
the script permissions are `-rwxrwxrwx. 1 user user 709  script.py` the owner of the script is the same as the user I use to run the script.

I do not understand why I get Permission denied when I run `./script.py` but I can run it with `python script.py` or `/usr/bin/python script.py`. What I am missing?

Linux distribution is RedHat 6

Comment: Which distribution are you using? E.g. on Fedora it could theoretically be a SELinux issue.

Comment: vol mounted with `noexec` ?

Comment: I was having this same issue until I made the file executable. Are you 100% sure that you have the executable bit on?

```chmod u+x script.py```

Comment: you could try using `strace -f` on the shell, then try to run the script, and see where you get the error

Comment: @steve you are right `/dev/mapper/systemvg-home on /home type ext4 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file-system where the script resides was mounted with 'NOEXEC' flag `/dev/mapper/systemvg-home on /home type ext4 (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)`